# Javascript (and JSP) won't create table properly with if statement

Tags: javascript, oracle, jsp

So i'm using multiple if statements to draw data from a database based on the users search criteria.

What i'm struggling with is

```
if(request.getParameter("searchProperty")!= ""){
     SearchStatement = "town_city = '" + request.getParameter("searchProperty") + "'";
     if(request.getParameter("bedrooms") != "0"){
                    SearchStatement += " AND bedrooms = '" + request.getParameter("bedrooms") + "'";
                }
     }
```

with the idea that this concatenates a string to use as a query in the database, and bring back the results the user is searching for (this is a property searching website). I thought i'd done the if statement correctly. From what i understand, from what i've put, if the user were to select 0 in bedrooms it should return ALL results, but instead it returns NONE (who wants a house without a bedroom..) Can somebody explain what's going wrong please?

here's where the SQL statement is built and input

```
MyProperties = bookSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PROPERTIES WHERE " + SearchStatement);
```

with the expected outcome being, for example

```
SELECT * FROM PROPERTIES WHERE Location = 'input' AND Bedrooms = 'value'
```

unless value = 0 where it should just be

```
SELECT * FROM PROPERTIES WHERE Location = 'input'
```

Comment: best way to avoid this mistakes is **printing the query before execution** so print and see what have you done

Comment: Yeah it looks like if i'm not specifying the value of bedrooms, it always includes 0 and doesn't pull anything through. I don't know why though or how to stop it.

So i'm getting
    SELECT * FROM PROPERTIES WHERE Location = 'input' AND Bedrooms = '0' which shouldn't be happening as that's what i'm telling it not to include with the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with this statement,

```
request.getParameter("bedrooms") != "0"
```

should be something like this ,

(!request.getParameter("bedrooms").isEmpty())

**Remember you are comparing the strings**

so if is "0"

```
 if(request.getParameter("bedrooms").equals("0")){
                   return SearchStatement ;
            }
else {
SearchStatement += " AND bedrooms = '" + request.getParameter("bedrooms") + "'"
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: To confirm, bedrooms is a drop down box with an initial value of 0 (i've actually specified the values), so it can't be empty. The only field which can be empty is "searchProperty" and if it is, there is an else statement which means that doesn't have the same issue. (if the search field is empty then everything is selected right now)

Comment: "cannot return a value from method whose result type is void" is given when i try changing my code to yours. 
Also, while i'm thinking about it (although it's unrelated) why is .equals "better" than ==?